# gwt custom listview with radiobutton & checkbox

Tags: java, gwt

I have a scenario in which I'll have a list view which will have the combination of checkboxes and radio buttons , in other words , the listview will have

**option1          checkbox[]**

**option2          radiobutton ()yes ()no**

Can you please anyone tell me how do I do that?

Comment: Is there any way I can do this implementation without listview? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you mean by list view? If you want to create a list of controls that consist of a checkbox and radio box, and to be selected only one list element at a tinge, Create a CellList with as custom cell of type CompositeCell (docs link http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/CompositeCell.html). Or you can create your own user defined cell by extending AbstractCell class and defining your requirement by overriding the render method.